# How to convert datepicker date to JSON object to use in AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui-datepicker

i'm using the jquery datepicked and i have this code to take the date from it:

```
var d = new Date(1980, 2, 2);
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        defaultDate: d,
        yearRange: '1970:2020',
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        monthNamesShort:    ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Maj','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Okt','Nov','Dec'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Ned', 'Pon', 'Vto', 'Sri', 'Chet', 'Pet', 'Sub']
    });
```

from there i get the date like this

```
var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker('getDate').getDate();                 
var dateToJson = date.ToJson();
```

I want to use this fullDate in ajax function, but every time i make the post it passes the parameter with the UTC timezone date/time. I need to pass only the current date with the offset of the timezone i am picking the date from( i am -7 hours from UTC so it is a big deal for like 1/3 of the day i have problems). How can i take the exact date to use in ajax request ?

Comment: can you show the ajax function ? or some more code, because i don't get what your problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug with the timezone offset when you do Date.ToJson() function. Eitherway you can make your own ToJsonLocal function to take only your local date when you need it. It looks something like this :

```
Date.prototype.toJSONLocal = (function() {
function addZ(n) {
    return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;
}
return function() {
  return this.getFullYear() + '-' +
         addZ(this.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
         addZ(this.getDate());
};
}())
```

When you pick the date from the datepicker convert it in your variable

```
var dateToLocalJson = date.ToJSONLocal();
```

and pass the json to the ajax. It should be ok this way.
Hope this helps ;]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the ISO date format in the full date object.  So, do something like this:

```
var fullDate = date.toISOString();
```

Then pass fullDate around to any ajax method you need.  I've found that date parsing and serialization is not standard across environments, and as much as I hate it, I just put everything to a string myself before sending it over the wire.

The docs for the method are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

To reverse, you just pass the string back to a date object:

```
var dateObj = new Date(fullDate);
```

May I make a small pitch to look into [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)?  I switched all of my projects over to Moment and have never looked back :)

Comment: the date.toISOString() returns again the UTC format while i need the local time. But about the momentJS good one i definatelly should try that

Comment: I would recommend using UTC on the wire protocol and when you store dates: Your users may be from all over the world and timezones of your server may change.  In C#, the parse method ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx ) will handle the ISO format automatically.  Plus in JavaScript, moment has a local() method to use whenever you want to display it to users.